# Video streaming with HTML5 video player

Tags: spring-boot, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to get into how the video streaming with HTML5 video player works and have some questions about that.

I have such a declaration at my HTML page

```html
        <video controls  class="card-img-top">
            <source src="/stream/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

The URL `/stream/video.mp4` is handled by the Spring Boot controller which sends the data. All works fine but how I see it very inefficient.

Every time I move the slider on the video timeline to any point I see the requests with `Range` header like

- Range: bytes=88375296-
- Range: bytes=39354368-
- Range: bytes=60915712-

That's mean at every video scroll I have to provide all the data from a specified point to the end of the video file. That looks really inefficient.

Is there some way to configure HTML5 player to work in more efficient way? Also, could you recommend something to read about video streaming implementation with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2):

> That's mean at every video scroll I have to provide all the data from a specified point to the end of the video file.

The browsers requests all the data form the specified point to the end of the file, BUT, it can simply disconnect the TCP session to stop the downloading when a seek happens. Its is as efficient as it can be.

> Is there some way to configure HTML5 player

No, When you tell the browser to play an MP4, you give ALL control to the browser. You there are no options to control how it works.

If you want more control, you can use Media Source Extensions. But then you will need to use more advanced file formats server side and implement all the details of how the player works. See HLS/DASH

Comment: I just found that for the `1234-` range request I can answer with a chunk of any size starting from 1234 byte.  Probably that's a way to avoid unnecessary reads. from file. Is that ok to use this approach?

Here is my current code
https://github.com/usharik/geek-video-stream/blob/master/geek-tube/src/main/java/ru/geektube/service/VideoStreamService.java

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that browsers will lower the TCP window size all the way to zero to prevent getting more data than they feel like buffering.